# Hide / Show element based on ULR Gatsby React

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to show / hide a P tag in the footer based on the url it is in.

I did it in development mode and it worked:

```js
{acf2.texto_2_rodape_coluna_2.length > 0  && window.location.href.indexOf("mydomain")? (
              <>
                <p className="contact">
                <HiCursorClick/> <Link to={acf2.link_call_1} style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>
                    {acf2.texto_2_rodape_coluna_2}
                  </Link>
                </p>
              </>
            ) : null}

            {acf2.texto_3_rodape_coluna_2.length > 0 && !window.location.href.indexOf("mydomain/")? (
              <p className="contact">
              <AiTwotoneVideoCamera/> <Link to={acf2.link_to_action_2} style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>
                  {acf2.texto_3_rodape_coluna_2}
                </Link>
              </p>
            ) : null}
```

In development mode it works, but when I send to netlify this error occurs:

error: "window" is not available during server side rendering.

WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are using `window` object in the server-side (SSR) where is not allowed since `gatsby develop` occurs on the browser-side but `gatsby build` (also Netlify deploy) occurs in the server where there [global objects such as `window` or `document` are not defined yet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (for obvious reasons).

In Gatsby, because it extends from the `@reach/router` (from React) you can access a [`prop` named `location`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) (only available in pages but you can pass downside to any children) with all the desired information without accessing the global objects. In your case:

```
{acf2.texto_2_rodape_coluna_2.length > 0  && location.pathname.includes('mydomain')? (
              <>
                <p className="contact">
                <HiCursorClick/> <Link to={acf2.link_call_1} style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>
                    {acf2.texto_2_rodape_coluna_2}
                  </Link>
                </p>
              </>
            ) : null}

            {acf2.texto_3_rodape_coluna_2.length > 0 && !location.pathname.includes('mydomain')? (
              <p className="contact">
              <AiTwotoneVideoCamera/> <Link to={acf2.link_to_action_2} style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>
                  {acf2.texto_3_rodape_coluna_2}
                </Link>
              </p>
            ) : null}
```

If you want to use your initial approach, you need to ensure that the window is defined as the documentation suggest by using:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  //your statement
}
```

Applied to your code:

```
{typeof window !== 'undefined' && acf2.texto_2_rodape_coluna_2.length > 0  && window.location.href.indexOf("mydomain")? (...)
```

Of course, it's not recommended since you have a native approach using `location`, and because chaining ternary conditions is not the best option in terms of code readability.